# Where do I place global overrides in a modular Backbone.js site?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, prototype, overriding

We use RequireJS to add modularity to our Backbone.js site. I found myself with the need to override the `Backbone.Collection` class to add an advance filtering routine.

My questions is, say I have the following 'override',

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.advanceFilter = function() {
     /* Filtering code here */
};
```

and our site structure looks like the following:

[image: Site Structure]

where, `main.js` sits at the top level and beneath it is `app.js`; Where would I add this override, such that I don't have to add a new module to our RequireJS definition for every class? More generally, where are overrides to Backbone usually recommended?

Answer (score 4):

Create a file (say Overrides.js in modules folder)

```
define(function(require){

    var app = require('app');

    Backbone.Collection.prototype.advanceFilter = function() {
       /* Filtering code here */
    };


    // other overrides can also be added here in this file like
    _.extend(Backbone.View.prototype,{}, {
        // adding functions or overriding something
    })
});
```

Now, require this file in main.js like

```
require([
    'backbone',
    'App',
    'modules/Overrides',
    'globalize',
    .
    .
    .
],
function ( Backbone, App, ..... ) {

});
```

There you go!

Say, I want to add some function to the view or override some function such as render, initialize, remove,... universally in the application. You could do something like this:

```
_.extend(Backbone.View.prototype,{}, { 

    remove: function() { 

        alert("View removed");
        this.$el.remove();
        this.stopListening(); 
        return this; 

    }

});
```

Comment: Excellent example. Could you expand a bit on how `_.extend(Backbone.View.prototype,{}, {...}` can be used to include additional overrides?

Comment: Say, I want to add some function to the view or override some function  such as render, initialize, remove ... overall in the application
For eg.

    _.extend(Backbone.View.prototype,{}, {
        remove: function() {
            alert("View removed");
            this.$el.remove();
            this.stopListening();
            return this;
        }
    });

Answer (score 2):

One easy option if using requirejs, in your require config add an init statement. eg,

```
require.config({
     shim: {
         'backbone': {
             deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
             exports: 'Backbone',
             init: function (_) {
                 Backbone.Collection.prototype.advanceFilter = function() {
                 /* Filtering code here */
                 };
             }
         }
     }
 });
```

Alternatively you can use a `map` config call to amp all backbone calls to your overridden backbone,

```
require.config({
    map: {
      '*': { 'backbone': 'backbone-custom' },
      'backbone-custom': { 'backbone': 'backbone' }
    }
});

// backbone-custom.js file:
define(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.advanceFilter = function() {
    /* Filtering code here */
    };

    return Backbone;
});
```

Either case will load the override into the backbone object before it is used anywhere.

Comment: I like your answer, and really wanted to mark it as such but @Bhavir's is a bit more intuitive (i.e. easier to understand/implement to dummies like myself). Thanks for bringing this functionality to my attention!